# Error while compiling .scss with Koala

Tags: css, user-interface, sass, koala

i don't know if this is the right section or if there is a section at all, so...sorry!

Anyway i was getting started with less and i was watching this tutorial:

"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pB7EwxwSfVk&list=PLillGF-RfqbZTASqIqdvm1R5mLrQq79CU&index=23"

At 10 minutes he compiles a .scss file with Koala and everything is fine, when i do it i get this error:

[image]

In the error box it's written .scs, but it's .scss actually. I guess it's a Koala error.

I've been searching on the Web but still i didn't get rid of the problem. Can you please help me?
I'm losing my mind!

Many thanks!

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem, but I would try it without `:` in the path name. Also this may be related: https://github.com/oklai/koala/issues/162 . And make sure you are using the latest Koala version.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.

I found the link you gave me this morning but i don't understand it.
everybody say things like 
set the timeout value in %koala%\app\scripts\compilers\SassCompiler.js" 
But i don't know where to find it! How can i reach that directory? I know i'm a total noob...forgive me

Comment: @juzraai MAN! you are a genius, now it works! It was the colon! Gosh why...
Anyway thanks a lot, have a nice day

Comment: You're welcome! :) I added it as answer too with some explanation. Please accept it for future reference.

Comment: thanks a lot, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed colon character `:` in your directory name and I think this can cause the problem, because `:` has a special meaning in Mac OS and Linux operating systems, it's the [pathname separator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311339/why-was-colon-chosen-as-path-separator) character.

I think the easiest solution is to **rename your directory so it won't contain `:`.**